# How do I get rid 'avformat.h' no such file or directory error while installing Video-ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, timecodes

I've been trying to install [Video-ffmpeg](http://search.cpan.org/~randomman/Video-FFmpeg-0.46/) but `sudo make` shows this error, `FFmpeg.xs:7:22: fatal error: avformat.h: No such file or directory. compilation terminated.`

I've libavformat53 installed on my m/c. Is there something I've to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need the headers of libavformat, which in ubuntu/debian are called libavformat-dev.

```
aptitude search libavformat
sudo aptitude reinstall libavformat53 libavformat-dev libavcodec53
```